# Python stopped working error message while using this script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

It only shows e that error message when i run this script:

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPalette, QBrush
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize    

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(500, 500))    
        self.setWindowTitle("Chercher des Personnes")

        oImage = QImage("i.jpg")
        sImage = oImage.scaled(QSize(300,200))                   # resize Image to widgets size
        palette = QPalette()
        palette.setBrush(10, QBrush(sImage))                     # 10 = Windowrole
        self.setPalette(palette)



        self.nameLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.Name = QLabel(self)
        self.Age = QLabel(self)
        self.Telnum = QLabel(self)
        self.Mail = QLabel(self)
        self.Adress = QLabel(self)

        self.nameLabel.setText('Prenom du personne:')
        self.Name.setText('Nom et Prenom: ')
        self.Age.setText('Age: ')
        self.Telnum.setText('Numero de Tel: ')
        self.Mail.setText('Email adress: ')
        self.Adress.setText('Adress: ')

        self.line = QLineEdit(self)

        self.line.move(150, 50)
        self.line.resize(200, 32)
        self.nameLabel.move(150, 20)
        self.Name.move(20, 150)
        self.Age.move(20, 180)
        self.Telnum.move(20, 210)
        self.Mail.move(20, 240)
        self.Adress.move(20, 270)

        pybutton = QPushButton('OK', self)
        pybutton.clicked.connect(self.clickMethod)
        pybutton.resize(200, 32)
        pybutton.move(150, 85)        

def clickMethod(self):
    class people:
        def __init__(self, full_name, birthday, telnum, mail, adress, other):
            self.name = full_name
            self.full_name = full_name
            self.birthday = birthday #ddmmyyyy
            self.telnum = telnum
            self.mail = mail
            self.adress = adress
            self.other = other


    #Peoples info
        john = people("Full name: John Doe", "Birthday: ??/01/2005 Age: 12", "Telephone number: +41 12 345 67 89", "Educanet2: fake@example", "Adress: 123 Fake Street, 1721 Suisse", "Other: John is a known programmer and plays ice hockey. He participates in robotics competitions. But he's bullied and made fun of at times")
         self.Name.setText(str(locals()[self.line.text().lower()].name ))








if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

The Indent spaces are not correct on the script here but it is on my real code. It will just take me too long to make 4 spaces for every line that's why.

So why am i getting this message: "Python stopped working"?
What can i do to fix it?

Ps: When using other scripts no error message like this occurs or when i replace the self.name.setText(" ") by a tkinter message box no error occurs

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish here.  But, your problem seems to be from your use of the `locals()` function.  If you are just trying to get the text from the line edit, change that line to `self.Name.setText(self.line.text().lower())`.

Comment: Well i'm trying using locals() to get information that i store in a class.

Comment: I think you may be confused about what locals does.  The way you have written your code, it will only work if the name you enter in the line edit is 'thibaut', because that is the variable assigned as the instance of your people class.  It will never be anything different.  So in that case, why not just use `self.Name.setText(thibaut.name)` as it is essentially a much less complicated version of the same thing.   Also, when running a pyqt5 application, if you will run it from your command line/terminal, it will output an error message for you to diagnose what is happening.

Comment: then why does it work when i do this:                                                   
                                                                                                              
lines = [str(locals()[self.line.text().lower()].name ),  ' ', str(locals()[self.line.text().lower()].birthday)]
        
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Text', "\n".join(lines))